# Rstudio3 can't launch from terminal or icons---------Rstudio3+ubuntu14.04LTS[Rstudio]

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio

I install R into ubuntu14.04LTS, and then download Rstudio3_i386.deb and installed it from software center successfully. However, when I try to launch from icons, ubuntu do nothings. Then I type"rstudio" in terminal. It give me this:
/usr/local/R-Studio/bin/R-Studio: error while loading shared libraries: librs_linux_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What's wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by doing the following:

```
cd /usr/local/R-Studio/lib
sudo rm -f librs_linux_r.so
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/R-Studio/lib/rs_linux_r.so librs_linux_r.so
```

There may be a better or more proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble under Ubuntu 14.10. Fixed it via a pair of lines:

```
cd /usr/local/R-Studio/bin/
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/R-Studio/lib/rs_linux_r.so librs_linux_r.so
```